# Hibernate Spatial Polygon Coordinate Orientation

Tags: oracle, hibernate, geometry, polygon, jts

I am using hibernate spatial (geolatte with JTS) with an oracle database. I am creating a Geometry object with a polygon so it is being persisted as an SDO_GEOMETRY object in the database. Currently all polygons are stored counter-clockwise with the SDO_ETYPE in the SDO_ELEM_INFO_ARRAY set to 1003 (exterior polygon ring). If I reverse the polygon and persist it the counter-clockwise orientation does not change.

So it appears that hibernate is enforcing this requirement or once the SDO_GEOMETRY object is created the orientation is set.

I would like to control which orientation the polygons are saved in the database. Is this a hibernate setting? Do I need to store the polygons as holes (interior rings) when I create them instead of shells?

Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Oracle demands a specific ordering as part of the SDO spec. Note I am the original author of the GeoTools code which has been cleaned up for use here in JTS.

For details see jacadoc examples, or the SDO docs.

Comment: Thanks so much for your reply! I have been doing searches and reading docs for two days, could you please provide a link on how to specify orientation?

Answer (score 0):

The Oracle Spatial documentation specifies Polygon ring orientation in Section 2.2.4:

https://docs.oracle.com/cd/A97630_01/appdev.920/a96630/sdo_objrelschema.htm#sthref198

Comment: Thanks! Yes I have read through that doc already. The polygons are being stored as SDO_ETYPE 1003 which means they are forced to counter clockwise. The question seems to be how do I change the SDO_ETYPE to 2003 using Java/Hibernate so the polygons are stored clockwise? I am currently working on setting the shell to null and a hole to the polygon (Polygon(LinearRing shell, LinearRing[] holes, GeometryFactory factory)) in the hope that this will result in a 2003 SDO_ETYPE.